# limit including box function

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification

Which of the following is/are correct ?

$(1)\lim_{x\to 0}\big[\frac x{sinx}\big]=1$

$(2)\lim_{x\to 0}\big[\frac x{cosx}\big]=0$

$(3)\lim_{x\to 0}\big[\frac {sinx}x\big]=0$

$(4)\lim_{x\to 0}\big[\frac {cosx}x\big]=1$

My attempt:-

We have $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{sinx}x=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac x{sinx}=1$

So for a given $\epsilon \gt 0, \exists \delta \gt 0$ such that

$1-\epsilon \lt \frac{sinx}x,\frac x{sinx}\lt 1+\epsilon, \forall x\in (-\delta,\delta)$ (Actually there are two $\delta$'s , I am selecting the minimum out of them.

Now if $ \sin x \lt$ or $\gt x$ according as $x\gt $ or $\lt 0$.

So for $x\in (0,\delta)$,

$1-\epsilon \lt \frac{\sin x}x \lt 1$

Thus $\lim_{x\to 0+}\big[\frac{\sin x}x \big]=0$

For $x\in (-\delta,0)$

$\sin x\gt x \Rightarrow \frac{\sin x}x\lt 1$ (since $x\lt 0$)

By similar reasoning as above

$\lim_{x\to 0-}\big[\frac{\sin x}x \big]=0$

Hence , $\lim_{x\to 0}\big[\frac{\sin x}x\big]=0$

In the case of $\frac x{\sin x}$ , we would have

$1\lt \frac x{\sin x}\lt 1+\epsilon$, for $x\in (-\delta,\delta)$

Thus $\lim_{x\to 0} \big[\frac x{\sin x}\big]=1$

So $(1)$ and $(3)$ are true

Well for $(4)$ ...

$\cos x\ge 1-\frac{x^2}2,\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

So for $x\gt 0$, we have

$\frac{\cos x}x\ge \frac 1x-\frac x2\to \infty$ as $x\to 0$

So the limit in $(4)$  does not exist.

For $(2)$,

Now , $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac x{\cos x}=0$

So for arbitary $\epsilon \gt 0, \exists \delta \gt 0$ such that

$-\epsilon  \lt \frac x{\cos x} \lt \epsilon$

Now for $x\in (0, \delta), 0\lt \frac x{\cos x}\lt \epsilon $ (since $\cos x\gt 0$ in close neighbourhood of zero) giving

$\lim_{x\to 0+} \big[\frac x{\cos x}\big]=0$

Similarly,
$\lim_{x\to 0-} \big[\frac x{\cos x}\big]=0$

Thus
$\lim_{x\to 0} \big[\frac x{\cos x}\big]=0$

So $(2)$ is true.

I request you to go through my solution and check if there is any technical difficulty.

I would like any alternative ideas. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Your solution looks perfectly fine to me

Comment: Once you know the limit without the 'entire part' exists, what is perhaps faster is to check whether the quantity inside the 'entire part' is greater than the limit or not. This avoids the use of $\varepsilon$'s